# Batch rename files, merge columns .csv?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have .csv file with 3 columns, delimiter is "|", .
I need to use it to rename files, last(3rd) column is current filename. First two field joined should be new file name.
As in example, some fields contain space, don't know is that could be a problem or not.
Files are in folder C:\all\ as well in sub folders in C:\all.

example:

```
New|Name 1|CurrentName1
```

`CurrentName1`> `New Name 1`

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2,3  delims=|" %%A in (C:\all\c.csv) do (
  for /R "C:\all\" %%C in ("%%~C") do (
ren "%%~C" "%%A %%B"
  )
)
:END
```

when I test, it started renaming sub folders, not files. I don't want to rename sub folders only files, how to fix that?

Comment: *N. B.:* guess what **C**SV stands for...

Comment: Does the thirst colum specify full file names or just the base name without extension (s. g., there is a file `test.txt`, so whyt does the third column contain -- `test` or `test.txt`)? and what about column two -- does it contain a new file extension, or should the original one be kept?

Answer (score 1):

A [`for [/R]` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) accesses the file system only when there is at least a [wildcard `*` or `?`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) in the set (that is the part in between parentheses behind the keyword `in`). So for example, `for %%I in (test.txt) do echo %%I` will always return `test.txt`, independent on whether or not such a file exists in the current working directory.

Instead of `for /R` to find a certain item in a directory tree you could use the [`dir` command](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html), which does not require a wildcard to actually check the file system:

```cmd
for /F "usebackq tokens=1-3 delims=| eol=|" %%I in ("C:\all\c.csv") do (
    for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /S /B /A:-D "%%K" 2^> nul') do (
        ECHO ren "%%F" "%%I %%J"
    )
)
```

This code check the full file name against the list file. If you want to check the base name only, replace `"%%K"` in the `dir` command line by `"%%K.*"`. If you want to keep the original file extension, replace `"%%I %%J"` in the `ren` command line by `"%%I %%J%%~xF"`.

**After having tested the code, remove the upper-case `ECHO` in front of the `ren` command.**